# How do I use my Personal Google ID with docker build when using Google Artifact Registry?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

Currently I have the following Docker file...

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk add curl gnupg
RUN (curl -Ls https://cli.doppler.com/install.sh || wget -qO- https://cli.doppler.com/install.sh) | sh
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY --chown=node:node . .
USER node
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/node/app/google-key.json
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=googlekey,target=/home/node/app/google-key.json
RUN npx --yes google-artifactregistry-auth
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["doppler", "run", "--", "npm", "start"]
```

This works great with a service account key, however, I don't want all of my developers to have permissions to create a service account key. I can't check the account key in for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to pass the person's personal creds into docker so they can build? All the users have read access to the registry.

Comment: You might want to check these [authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication).

Comment: @Jackie did you ever get this figured out?